# Racket, applying list of functions: abstract list functions

Tags: list, function, scheme, racket, abstract

I want to create a function using abstract list functions that will apply a list of functions onto each other, without a starting element (take the starting point as 0)

So  '(list add1 sqr add1) -> 2

What I have so far creates a list of what those function do individually, so for the above example '(1 0 1)

Any help? An explanation would be nice if you could spare one, I'm still iffy about things such as foldr, map, etc

```
     (define (apply_functions lof)
     (map (lambda (lof) (lof 0)) lof))
```

I previously defined a composite function as below in case its helpful at all?

```
     (define (composite f g)
      (lambda (x) (f (g x))))
```

Could the initial problem also be translated to a function which takes in a list of function and an initial number (other than 0) and produces the number result

for example:
'( add1 sqr sub1) 4 -> 10

EDIT::

So looking at the question, it wanted something such as (check-expect ((composite-list (list add1 sqr sub1)) 3) 5), where the start number is not included as a variable. I've tried multiple variations of the code but can't make it work.

Comment: i'm sorry, I figured if I kept the accept on the question, it would seem as if the question had not been added to if that makes any sense. I put it back. And thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a perfect situation for using [`foldr`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._foldr%29%29), it behaves as expected:

```
(define (apply-functions lof)
  (foldr (lambda (f acc) (f acc))
         0
         lof))

(apply-functions (list add1 sqr add1))
=> 2
```

It works because we apply each `f` in turn to the accumulated result, starting with `0`. Notice that `foldr` applies the functions in the list in a right-to-left order (that is: the first function applied is the last one in the list, then the result of that is passed to the second-to-last function and so on). If you want to enforce a left-to-right order use `foldl` instead.

For the last part of your question (after the edit): we can start with a different initial number by simply passing the right parameter to `foldr`, and returning a curried function:

```
(define ((composite-list lof) init)
  (foldr (lambda (f acc) (f acc))
         init
         lof))

((composite-list (list add1 sqr sub1)) 3)
=> 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even do it more general than that. You can actually make a generic compose:

```
(define (my-compose . procedures)
  (let* ((proc-in-order   (reverse procedures))
         (init-proc       (car proc-in-order))
         (remaining-procs (cdr proc-in-order)))
    (lambda g 
      (foldl (lambda (x acc) (x acc))         
             (apply init-proc g)
             remaining-procs))))

;; test first makes a list of it's arguments, 
;; then takes the length, then negates that value
(define test (my-compose - length list))

(test 1 2 3 4) ; ==> -4
```

The first procedure in the chain (last argument) is applied with the initial argument as a list so it takes many arguments while the rest of the chain takes exactly one.